# setting margin of article tag inside a section affects section's margin

Tags: html, css

First of all sorry for my bad English.

I am styling the layout this way:

I have a `section` with class name `page-container` that contains pages. It slides pages using javascript. inside page container `section` I have other sections that represent every single page and each contains an `article` as content of the page.

```
<section class="page-container">
    <section id="homepage-pg" class="page">
        <article>
            <header></header>
            <p></p>
        </article>
    </section>
    ...
</section>
```

The problem is when I style these tags and set a `margin-top` for the `article`, it affects on `margin-top` of its parent `section`. But it works when I insert `&nbsp;` or any character between the page `section` and the `article` like this:

```
<section class="page-container">
    <section id="homepage-pg" class="page">
        &nbsp; or any characters here!!!
        <article>
            <header></header>
            <p></p>
        </article>
    </section>
    ...
</section>
```

[Here's jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/er0dmqet/)

So I'm wondering what's the problem?

CSS:

```
section.page-container, section.page {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

section.page-container {
    position: absolute;
    padding:0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}

section.page {
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
}

section.page > article {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 700px;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: visible;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is occurring because the [margins are collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins).

> [**Box Model 8.3.1 Collapsing margins**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)
>
> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined margin is called a collapsed margin.
>
> When two or more margins collapse, the resulting margin width is the maximum of the collapsing margins' widths. In the case of negative margins, the maximum of the absolute values of the negative adjoining margins is deducted from the maximum of the positive adjoining margins. If there are no positive margins, the maximum of the absolute values of the adjoining margins is deducted from zero.

One possible workaround is to change the `overflow` value of the parent element to something other than `visible`. Adding `overflow: hidden` works.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6uo42kx0/)

```
section.page {
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden; /* Added.. */
}
```

That was one of the rules specified in the documentation I linked to above:

> Margins of elements that establish new block formatting contexts (such as floats and elements with 'overflow' other than 'visible') do not collapse with their in-flow children. [**[link]**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

For more workarounds, check out [the documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins).